# Minimal polynomial of the operator $T:V\oplus W\to V\oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ and let $T_{1}:V\to V$ and $T_{2}:W\to W$ be two linear transformations whose minimal polynomials are given by $f_{1}(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$ and $f_{2}(x)=x^{4}-x^{2}-2$.

Let, $T:V\oplus W\to V\oplus W$ be the linear transformation defined by

$T(v,w)=(T_{1}(v),T_{2}(w))$ for $(v,w)\in V\oplus W$ and let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Then which of the followings are correct?

(1) $\deg(f(x))=7$

(2) $\deg(f(x))=5$

(3) $\mathrm{nullity}(T)=1$

(4) $\mathrm{nullity}(T)=0$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

- The minimal polynomial of $T$ is the least common multiple of $f_1$ and $f_2$.Hence minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(x^2+1)(x^2-2)(x+1)$.
- $\operatorname{\eta}(T)\ne0$ if and only if $0$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $T$ if and only if $0$ is a root of $f_1$ or $f_2$ which isn't the case.

Comment: Sir, I know that for a block diagonal matrix minimal polynomial is the l.c.m. of the minimal polynomials of each block & the proof is known to me.But for linear transformation (in particular for this problem) how we can show the result?

Comment: It's basically the same proof. The minimal polynomial of $T$ should annihilate $T_1$ and $T_2$ so it's a multiple of $f_1$ and $f_2$ since they are the minimal polynomial of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Finally by the minimality of the degree we see that this minimal polynomial is the l.c.m. of $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: Your assertion of coprimality is erroneous; not having a common root (in $\Bbb R$) is not a sufficient condition for this. Also, the nullity of $T$ is **not** the multiplicity of $0$ as root of the characteristic polynomial, in general (nor that as root of the minimal polynomial). But indeed since it cannot exceed the multiplicity (in the characteristic polynomial), if the latter is $0$ then so must the nullity.

Comment: My assertion is correct in $\Bbb C$ and this what I meant since even $T$ is over $\Bbb R$ we may see it in an algebraically closed field  and I didn't say or use in my answer that the nullity is the multiplicity but I said that $\ker T\ne\{0\}$ iff $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ iff $0$ is a root for the minimal polynomial so in MHO you objection has no sense @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: I tried to say this more subtly, but apparently to no effect, so I'll have be a bit more blunt. (1) Do you maintain that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are coprime, in spite of having a common factor $x^2+1$ as you can read in my answer (and two common roots $\mathbf i$, $-\mathbf i$ in$~\Bbb C$, now that you brought this up)? (2) The other remark was a literal citation from your first comment below the answer, not a comment on the answer itself (which does not mention the characteristic polynomial). If you no longer agree with that comment, you could delete it.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right in your two remarks, I didn't see that the two polynomials have common roots and of course in this case the answer is the l.c.m of the two polynomials. For my comment which is an answer to question deleted by the OP and I forget  the context  but obviously in the general case it isn't correct. I'll delete both the answer and the comment. Thanks.@MarcvanLeeuwen

Answer (score 8):

Although the currently accepted answer says otherwise, the polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not coprime; applying the Euclidean algorithm shows that $\gcd(x^3+x^2+x+1,x^4-x^2-2)=x^2+1$. It then follows that the minimal polynomial$~f$ of$~T$, which is the least common multiple of $f_1$ and $f_2$ as it is the least degree monic polynomial whose evaluation in the restrictions $T_1$ and $T_2$ of$~T$ to $W_1,W_2$ are both zero, equals $x^5+x^4-x^3-x^2+2x+2$. This polynomial having nonzero constant term means that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of$~T$ (root of$~f$), so $T$ is invertible and has nullity$~0$. So answers (2),(4) are correct.